# How to dynamically load module in react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I am currently working on adding support for [Sentry.io](https://sentry.io/timetarget/) in my react-native app. I use [react-native-sentry](https://github.com/getsentry/react-native-sentry) package and there is one requirement: the package should only be imported if certain constant is set to true, for example `SHOULD_USE_SENTRY`. All sentry configuration is stored in a separate file, which also exposes 2 methods: `setupSentry` and `captureException` which are used in the root of the app in the `componentDidMount` and `componentDidCatch` respectively. How can I dynamically load those methods in the root component, so that when the value of `SHOULD_USE_SENTRY` is `false` I won't get errors thrown after calling my methods? I hope I described my issue clear enough.

Answer (score 5):

You can't import on condition.

But you can do something similar by creating 2 entry points:
***folderA/index.js***   and 
***folderB/index.js***

***folderA/index.js*** there you import your module 
and pass it to your app through props.

```
import {someModule} from 'someModule';
render(){
    return(<App module={someModule} />);
}
```

***folderB/index.js*** there you don't import the module, and you pass **null** instead (or any other value you want)

```
render(){
    return(<App module={null} />);
}
```

then in your app component you can now have a condition

***App.js***

```
if(this.props.module != null){
    this.props.module.someFunction(); 
}
```

The only thing left to do is to chose to correct entry point when you start your packager. Use one of the command below depending on your rn version:

> react-native start --root folderA
>
> react-native start --projectRoot folderA

By specifying **--root**  or  **--projectRoot** you are telling to the packager to look for the index.js file in the folder you want. You can use this trick if you want different configuration for your project.